# Structure group of quaternionic manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, quaternions, principal-bundles, kahler-manifolds

*Quaternionic manifolds, also called almost hypercomplex, are defined by the existence of an ($\mathbb{R}$-linear) action of quaternions on each tangent space such that $I,J,K\in\mathbb{H}$ are global sections of $\operatorname{End} TX$.*

Several classes of manifolds can be defined by the reduction of their structure group from $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ to a subgroup:

- $O(n)$: Riemannian manifold ($\exists g$ symmetric positive);
- $Sp(2(n/2),\mathbb{R})$: almost symplectic manifold ($\exists\omega$ nondegenerate $2$-form);
- $GL(n/2, \mathbb{C})$: almost complex manifold ($\exists J\in\operatorname{End}(TX)$ with $J^2=-1$)
- $U(n/2)$: almost Hermitian manifold ($\exists\omega,J$ as above)
- **Can we put a group here?**: almost hypercomplex manifold ($\exists I, J, K\in\operatorname{End}(TX)$ with $I^2=J^2=K^2=IJK=-1$)

For completeness, let me recall the following.  A reduction to $G\subset GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is a section of the quotient by $G$ of the tangent frame bundle, namely a (continuous) choice at each point of a "copy of $G$" ($G$-torsor) among bases of the tangent space.

For example a reduction to $O(n)$ is a (continuous) choice of which bases of tangent space are orthonormal.  Similarly a reduction to $GL(n/2, \mathbb{C})$ is a choice of which bases are compatible with the almost complex structure $J$.

Comment: It's $GL(n/4,\Bbb H)$. If you want the hypercomplex structure to be compatible with a quaternionic inner product, it's the compact symplectic group $\text{Sp}(n/4)$.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks!  Can you clarify what compatible with quaternionic inner product means?  Am I right that it requires a Riemannian metric?

For the record: $GL(n/4,\mathbb{H})$ is also called $U^*(n/2)$ and is a real form of $GL(n/2,\mathbb{C})$ (cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_group#GL.28n.2C_H.29_and_SL.28n.2C_H.29 ).

Comment: It has been a long time since the question was asked. Anyway, I would like to point out two remarks. First, regarding user98602's comment, the quaternionic product he means is (on $\mathbb H^n$) $x\dot y = \sum_i \overline x_iy_i$. On the other hand, quaternionic manifolds are not what you describe in your question. In fact, quaternionic manifolds generalise hypercomplex in the sense that complex structures exits only locally. Then, the structure group of such manifolds is $GL(n/4,\mathbb H)GL(1,\mathbb H)$, not only $GL(n/4,\mathbb H)$.